# How can I ensure that stdole.dll is installed?

Tags: vb.net, com, activex, dllregistration, stdole

I have a project that uses the [CodeJock CommandBars](http://www.codejock.com/products/commandbars/?2yn6s14z=p1z) to provide a ribbon control interface (it is an [ActiveX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX) control).

This component requires the stdole.dll, but I have just installed on a machine with Microsoft Office and this DLL file is not in the [GAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache). Licensing restrictions forbid you to redistribute this DLL file, so where do I go from here?

I found a [redistribution for the Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=20923), but when I tried to install this it said Microsoft Office was required.

Comment: Well, that's sloppy.  Surely you are not the first CodeJock customer with this problem, so call them first.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c6f432b7-b810-4403-a3b3-641af29da3ef/how-can-i-include-stdoledll-in-my-net-20-project?forum=winformssetup